# .install Command not found while installing PopcornTime

Tags: linux, ubuntu, terminal, installation, tar

I am trying to install Popcorntime in ubuntu 14.04 from .tar. I have extracted .tar successfully. Then according to [this](https://www.4teq.com/2015/09/install-popcorn-time-in-linux.html) link I have written sudo .install while I was in my extracted folder. But I get "sudo: .install: command not found". Also there is no .install file in my extracted folder. What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

> I have written sudo .install while I was in my extracted folder. But I
>   get "sudo: .install: command not found"

The command given there isn't `sudo .install`; it is `sudo ./install`. You have missed a `/` in between . and install.

And, `.` represents current(present) directory in which you are(here /opt/popcorntime), as displayed on the terminal.

So, install is a file inside the current directory *(install is a file inside the **/opt/popcorntime/** directory)* , which would be `/opt/popcorntime` here; since you have done `cd /opt/popcorntime` in the previous step.

I hope it resolves your query.

Comment: Inside popcorntime there are three files as I mentioned before.These are libffmpegsumo.so , nw.pak , Popcorn-Time. But no install file

Comment: and sorry I have used sudo ./install command,but while asking question I have typed sudo .install. My bad!

Comment: @shadman_264 - Well, that is your and that website's issue! I can't verify that here. I suggest you to clean the files and re-install file as per your system's architecture(32/64 bit). I expect that it should work!

Answer (score 0):

If the executable "install" file is not found in the extracted package then it is probably a pre-installed package. In this case there should be an executable file called Popcorn-Time, and all you have to do is type the following command ./Popcorn-Time and the application will be launched.